# JQuery, ajax and js OOP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, oop

I have the following code:

```
var Foo = function(){
    this._temp="uh";
};

Foo.prototype._handler=function(data, textStatus){
    alert(this._temp);
}

Foo.prototype.run=function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '....', 
        success: this._handler
    });
}
```

So when I rum it:

```
new Foo().run();
```

And ajax query has come back, the handler is processed and I get error that `this._temp is undefined`. What is the reason and how to fix it using this code template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '....', 
    success: this._handler.bind(this)
});
```

You need to bind the context of the function.

If you using the debugger (available in the web browser), you will see that `this` was not referring to your object instance.